# A question on subsets of open sets with no accumulation points

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

If $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ open and suppose $S\subset U$ has no accumulation points in $U$. Let $z\in$ $U$\ $S$. Then can we say there exists an open disk $D_r(z)$ such that $\overline{D}_r(z)\subset U$? I came across this in a proof and can't really see how this is possible.

Comment: Do you mean $\overline D_r(z)\subset Z\setminus S$?

Comment: @John Nope what I have mentioned is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with $S$.... Indeed, for all $z\in U$, as $U$ is open, there is $r'>0$ so that $D_{r'} (z) \subset U$. Now choose $r = r'/2$. Then $\overline{D}_r(z) \subset U$.